# How to upload/Create new Template to Docusign from Salesforce by code?

Tags: apex, integration, docusign

Is it possible to create Docusign template creation from Salesforce via code.

I didn't get any steps/documentations of this.

I want to create declrative way, so i can create template to Docusign without logging there.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the DocuSign for Salesforce manage package itself. But, the short answer is yes it's possible. However, I don't think worth the effort (or recommended) as it would require writing an apex class from scratch and integrating directly with [DocuSign's SOAP API](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm).